# Tag "financial-data" should be for curated FinancialData not functions for finance

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have retagged [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4430/8) because it didn't actually use the curated `FinancialData` functionality. In doing so I have created a [finance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag.

To be honest, I think there should be a single tag for the various curated data calls (`FinancialData`, `CityData`, `ChemicalData` etc).

Comment: there is a [tag:curated-data] tag :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say this: as R.M commented, there is a [curated-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curated-data) tag, and I have already retagged some [country-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/country-data) questions into [curated-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curated-data) in the past. I suggest we do some more retagging, and introduce the specific functions as tag synonyms of [curated-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curated-data) if in the future other users tend to recreate these overly narrow tags.

As I think it has been discussed here in the past, the bar should be quite high for a single Mathematica function to have its own tag. Having [curated-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curated-data) instead of many [xxxxx-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxxxx-data) tags seems a good example of that general rule.

---

PS: you can also vote for the new [“financial-data” tag synonym](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/curated-data/synonyms) of “curated-data”.

Comment: You need rep in the tag (!) so I can't

Comment: I'll be voting on that. However, I feel "Curated data" is a phrase out of Wolfram's publicity engine which is not that common elsewhere. I suppose that many Mathematica users who have questions about `FinancialData` wouldn't think of using [tag:curated-data] as a tag.

Comment: I voted too.  I share Sjoerd's concern, but I also agree with Verbeia and F'x that it would be advantageous to have one common tag for all these.

Comment: In my opinion, domain-specific tags are more useful for those looking for specific answers than general containers. While [tag:curated-data] is fine on its own, very different issues arise using e.g. `CountryData` and `ChemicalData`. Of course if we settle on using specific tags, than [tag:curated-data] would be redundant and perhaps confusing too.